# Which was is it to best declare a property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If you are building a function type class in JavaScript when you declare a variable is it better to do it with

```
  var this.variableName = variableName 
  var this.x = x
```

or is it better to just do it like this.

```
  this.x
```

I tried using the var and it gave an error in Google debuger. Why would this be the case or are properties different than a variable that is set in a function "object".

Code:

```
function Circle(x,y,r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    // I've added the drawing code to the actual circle
    // they can draw themselves.
    this.draw = function(context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `var this.x = x` is an illegal statement...

Comment: `this.x` doesn't do anything but access an undefined property, it is not a declaration!

Answer (score 0):

When an object is declared, it is already declared, so doing something like this is, not only illegal, but also redundant.

```
// DON'T DO THIS!!!
var this.a = 'a'; // NO!!!!!!!!!
```

Instead, just declare your object and then just append things to that object, since it's already  initialized

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 'a';
obj.b = 'b';
```

The problem you'll probably face when declaring a function in your object is a matter of scope and how `this` works in Javascript.

For this, you have a couple of alternatives:

Declare a `that` variable that you can then use in your function:

```
function Circle(x,y,r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    // I've added the drawing code to the actual circle
    // they can draw themselves.
    var that = this;
    this.draw = function(context){

        // this refers to the global object (window)
        // that refers to your Circle Object
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(that.x, that.y, that.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }
}
```

If you're using an ECMAScript 5 supported browser (not IE8), you can bind the function to your `Circle` object.

```
function Circle(x,y,r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    // I've added the drawing code to the actual circle
    // they can draw themselves.


    this.draw = function(context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }.bind(this);
}
```

If you want to support IE8 and use `.bind`, you can just use underscore.js and use the `_.bind` function.

```
function Circle(x,y,r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    // I've added the drawing code to the actual circle
    // they can draw themselves.


    this.draw = _.bind(function(context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }, this);
}
```